# need suggestions on defining the width of columns

Tags: linux, shell

I need some ideas/suggestions on how to achieve the below task, I want to pen a simple shell script that should be able to do this task.

I have a file called abc.txt, it has 10 columns and is tab delimited, I want to read this file and define columns based on specified width; lets say 
    first column width=5 spaces, 
    2nd Column width=3 spaces,
    3rd column width= 4 spaces

so on and so forth....

the data in abc.txt adheres to this need but its just Tab delimited and at times not all of the width is consumed like first column is 5 spaces but might just have 4 characters in it.

Any suggestions on how best can i get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample input would be nice.

GNU awk can read fixed width data: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html#Constant-Size

If you want to transform your tab-separated file into your fixed width format:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read f1 f2 f3; do
    printf "%-5s%-3d%-4s\n" "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"
done < input > output
```